# Multiple projects from one setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

My current [setup.py](http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/fa55575e26b188de9b9b9f0c41d52c2a45400796/setup.py) (using setuptools) installs two things, one is `tvdb_api` (an API wrapper), the other is `tvnamer` (a command line script)

I wish to make the two available separately, so a user can do..

```
easy_install tvdb_api
```

..to only get the API wrapper, or..

```
easy_install tvnamer
```

..to install tvnamer (and tvdb_api, as a requirement)

Is this possible without having two separate `setup.py` scripts? Can you have two separate PyPi packages that come from the same `python setup.py upload` command..?

Comment: What's wrong with two setup.py scripts?

Comment: Yeh, that seems to be the way to do it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setup.py` is just a regular Python file, which by convention sets up packages.  By convention, `setup.py` contains a call to the setuptools or distutils `setup()` function. If you want to use one `setup.py` for two packages, you can call a different `setup()` function based on a command-line argument:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'script':
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv[2:]
    setup(name='tvnamer', ...)
else:
    setup(name='tvdb_api', ...)
```

Practically, though, I'd recommend just writing two scripts.

Comment: `sys.args` doesn't exist, did you mean `sys.argv`?

Comment: @ncocacola: yeah, that is what he must have meat. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I suspect this won't work without `pop`-ing the first argument. Otherwise, IMO setup() will treat it as one of the parameters for the setup command line interface.