# Is it safe to call `setup()` multiple times in a single `setup.py`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils

I am developing a package containing Cython extensions.

According to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1958 I shall use `setup_requires` and postpone import of `Cython`.
The best solution I came up with is to call `setup()` twice in `setup.py`:

```
... # initial imports
setup(setup_requires=['cython'])
from Cython.Build import cythonize
bar = Extension('foo.bar', sources = ['bar.pyx'])
setup(name = 'foo',
      ... # parameters
      ext_modules = cythonize([bar]),
      ... # more parameters
      )
```

However I have a feeling that the name of `setup()` suggests it shall be called only once. Is it safe to call it several times like I do?

I can not just distribute wheels because the package shall be available also for Linux users.

[EDIT]

Also I see the question as more general than dealing with compiler-dependencies. One may want to import some package (eg. `sphinx` or `pweave`) to preprocess the description of ones package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: **No**. Once you call setup, it will parse the command line arguments and start doing its job.

As for `Cython` dependency, `setup_requires` cannot help here. It will probably try to download `Cython` without installing. As SpotlightKid commented:

> distutils doesn't try to be a compiler or install gcc as a dependency either

According to the [setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html)

> this argument (setup_requires) is needed if you are using distutils extensions,

and thus, not for packages like `Cython`.

I think the user is responsible to install `Cython` before calling `setup.py`. If you want to provide more friendly error message, try to use

```
try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
except ImportError:
    # Kindly ask the user to install Cython
```

The following posts may help:

- [Install package which has setup_requires ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27789623/6238076)
- [setup_requires for dev environments](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2015-March/025882.html)

Comment: "it will parse the command line arguments and start doing its job" - it is exactly what made me doubt, but is it explicitly mentioned somewhere in the docs? Someone may wanted to inject a non-compiler dependency in a similar pattern.

Comment: @abukaj It is not mentioned in the docs, but you can easily find it out in the [source](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/48c42eeaee4410d76675b637bcd401b8919ff19a/core.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#core.py-59). More important is: even if it is safe to do so, the setuptools doesn't really help in this situation.

Answer (score 8):

I had a different scenario where I needed to run `setup()` multiple times: in my case I was building two packages from the same sources. First package was a command line tool based on `Fabric`, second package was only library (APIs, tooling, etc.) It seemed too impractical to split the project to two repositories for such a small project, since the CLI part was really only a wrapper. Running `setup()` multiple times with different arguments caused build crashing on various errors (mostly missing files). My solution was to run each `setup()` as different `Process`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setups = [
        {
            'name': 'cli-tool',
            'description': 'Some description...',
            'packages': find_packages(),
            'entry_points': {
                'console_scripts': [
                    'cli-tool = fabfile:main'
                ]
            },
            '...': 'etc. needed for setup() ...'
        },
        {
            'name': 'cli-tool-lib',
            'packages': find_packages(exclude=('fabfile',)),
            '...': 'etc.'
        }
    ]

    for s in setups:
        name = s['name']
        print("Building '{}'.".format(name))
        p = Process(target=setup, kwargs=s)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print("Building of '{}' done.\n".format(name))
```

Comment: It doesn't work with `pip install .`. My solution is to have two setup.py files in different directories. So user have to install via `pip install ./subdirectory1 ./subdirectory2` (and for git+ urls use  `#egg=...&subdirectory=...`).

Comment: I prefer this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/770247/1763602